# Video call by webrtc works in avd but not in real phone

Tags: android, flutter, webrtc, flutter-webrtc

Video call with webrtc works well in avd, but the call is not established inside the real phone.
I guess that the problem is in this part
"W/main_texture_ca( 4178): type=1400 audit(0.0:151571): avc: denied { getattr } for name="dmabuf:" dev="dmabuf" ino=1 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c151 ,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=filesystem permissive=0 "
Because AVD does not show such a thing, but I don't know how to solve this problem!
In general, the following output is written in the console

```
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 4178): onAddTrack
I/flutter ( 4178): Signaling state change: RTCSignalingState.RTCSignalingStateHaveRemoteOffer
I/flutter ( 4178): Add remote stream
W/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 4178): FlutterRTCVideoRenderer.setVideoTrack, set video track to a13e526e-fc21-4921-84be-20db79990691
I/BufferQueueProducer( 4178): [SurfaceTexture-0-4178-14](id:105200000016,api:1,p:4178,c:4178) disconnect: api 1
D/libMEOW ( 4178): meow delete tls: 0xb40000747d831580
D/libMEOW ( 4178): meow new tls: 0xb40000747d831580
D/libMEOW ( 4178): applied 0 plugin for [com.example.meetoy].
I/BufferQueueProducer( 4178): [SurfaceTexture-0-4178-14](id:105200000016,api:1,p:4178,c:4178) connect: api=1 producerControlledByApp=true
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 4178): onIceGatheringChangeGATHERING
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 4178): onIceCandidate
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 4178): onIceCandidate
I/flutter ( 4178): Signaling state change: RTCSignalingState.RTCSignalingStateStable
I/flutter ( 4178): ICE connection state change: RTCIceGatheringState.RTCIceGatheringStateGathering
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 4178): onConnectionChangeCONNECTING
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 4178): onIceCandidate
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 4178): onIceCandidate
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 4178): onIceCandidate
I/flutter ( 4178): Connection state change: RTCPeerConnectionState.RTCPeerConnectionStateConnecting
I/mali_config( 4178): @get_buffer_dataspace_setting: update dataspace from GE (0x10020000 -> 0x08020000)
W/main_texture_ca( 4178): type=1400 audit(0.0:151571): avc: denied { getattr } for name="dmabuf:" dev="dmabuf" ino=1 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c151,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=filesystem permissive=0 app=com.example.meetoy
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 4178): onIceGatheringChangeCOMPLETE
I/flutter ( 4178): ICE connection state change: RTCIceGatheringState.RTCIceGatheringStateComplete
```

Comment: Have you find the solution of this problem? Because I exactly have same problem in my video call app with flutter webrtc.

Comment: You must create a trun server

@khushbumovaliya

Comment: I have created turn server and set them in iceServers but still have same issue. always get RTCPeerConnectionState.RTCPeerConnectionStateFailed error. can you please share your flutter video call code?